# tcolorbox: Also make rules transparent

Tags: amsmath, tcolorbox, transparency

I would like to completely hide the contents of `tcolorboxes` (on non-white, non-uniform background), even all rules in equations. The latter are the only remaining things when one sets `opacitytext=0`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, opacitytext=0]
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}=\underline{c}
\end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to also hide the remaining lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the option `tikz={opacity=0}` in addition to `opacitytext=0` in order to hide anything inside the box, since the `enhanced` skin style uses `tikzpicture` as the drawing 'machine' -- the option `tikz={opacity=0}` is handed over to `tikzpicture` and drawing is 'silenced'.

The first box shows the hidden content, the second one is the box without using  `tikz={opacity=0}` as done by the O.P.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,opacitytext=0.0,tikz={opacity=0}]
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}=\underline{c}
\end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,opacitytext=0.0]
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}=\underline{c}
\end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you really need (might be an X-Y problem), but the following code hides the complete contents of your colorbox:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced] %now optional: opacitytext=0
        \phantom{%
            \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
                \begin{align}
                    \frac{a}{b}=\underline{c}
                \end{align}
        \end{minipage}%
    }%
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Explanation:

- `\phantom` occupies the space of its contents, but does not display it
- `minipage` makes it possible to use `align` in the `\phantom`

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is that one has to use `\phantom` each time explicitly for all boxes for which the content should be hidden.